logback logger (1.5.0) with Eclipse 4.31 -> No SLF4J providers were found
I use eclipse 4.31 with slf4j.api 2.0.12 and ch.qos.logback.classic 1.5.0. But if i want to log something i get following:
SLF4J(W): No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J(W): Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J(W): See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.

I created the eclipse RCP described here:
https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html
And the logback logger similar to here (i user later versions):
https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseLogging/article.html
Here the target platform:
<target name="target" sequenceNumber="43">
<locations>
    <location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
        <repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.31/"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group" version="3.19.400.v20240229-0520"/>                                                                                                
        <unit id="org.eclipse.pde.feature.group" version="3.15.300.v20240229-0520"/>                                                                                                
        <unit id="org.eclipse.platform.ide" version="4.31.0.I20240229-0520"/>                                                                                               
        <unit id="org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group" version="4.31.0.v20240229-0520"/>                                                                                              
        <unit id="org.eclipse.sdk.ide" version="4.31.0.I20240229-0520"/>                                                                       
        <unit id="org.eclipse.jdt.source.feature.group" version="3.19.400.v20240229-0520"/>            
        <unit id="org.eclipse.pde.source.feature.group" version="3.15.300.v20240229-0520"/>                                                       
        <unit id="org.eclipse.rcp.source.feature.group" version="4.31.0.v20240229-0520"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.emf.ecore.feature.group" version="2.37.0.v20240203-0859"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.ecf.core.feature.feature.group" version="1.6.2.v20231021-2127"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.emf.common.feature.group" version="2.31.0.v20231210-0956"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.equinox.sdk.feature.group" version="3.23.1100.v20240218-1855"/>
    </location>
    <location includeAllPlatforms="false" includeConfigurePhase="true" includeMode="planner" includeSource="true" type="InstallableUnit">
        <repository location="https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2024-03"/>
        <unit id="org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group" version="2.6.0.20240217-1525"/>
    </location>
</locations>
</target>

The Manifest:
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Rcp
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.example.e4.rcp;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Vendor: EXAMPLE
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.swt,
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench,
 org.eclipse.jface,
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.services,
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench,
 org.eclipse.e4.core.di,
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.di,
 org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 slf4j.api;bundle-version="2.0.12",
 ch.qos.logback.classic;bundle-version="1.5.0",
 ch.qos.logback.core;bundle-version="1.5.0"
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-17
Import-Package: jakarta.annotation;version="[2.1.0,3.0.0)",
 jakarta.inject;version="[2.0.0,3.0.0)"
Automatic-Module-Name: com.example.e4.rcp

Class with Logging (go to Menu->Help->About to execute this code):
package com.example.e4.rcp.handlers;

import org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations.Execute;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class AboutHandler {
        
    @Execute
    public void execute(Shell shell) {
        
        Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AboutHandler.class);
    }
}

The product:
<product name="com.example.e4.rcp" id="com.example.e4.rcp.product" application="org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.E4Application" version="1.0.0.qualifier" type="mixed" includeLaunchers="true" autoIncludeRequirements="true">

   <configIni use="default">
   </configIni>

   <launcherArgs>
      <programArgs>-clearPersistedState
      </programArgs>
      <vmArgsMac>-XstartOnFirstThread -Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts
      </vmArgsMac>
   </launcherArgs>

   <windowImages/>

   <plugins>
      <plugin id="com.example.e4.rcp"/>
   </plugins>

   <features>
      <feature id="org.eclipse.e4.rcp"/>
      <feature id="org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature" installMode="root"/>
   </features>


</product>

According to the manual here the logback-classic.jar on the class path will solve the problem:
https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders
I would say the ch.qos.logback.classic is the logback-classic.jar in classpath. But problem still exists.

You can do it like the IDE packages by including the org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature or like the Eclipse SDK using the slf4j.simple plugin which needs to be started explicitly+ -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel=off.

Adding this to product alone do not fix problem:
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

It seems eclipse plugin system changed to felix. Maybe this is the reason. I found a manual here:
https://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-logback.html

The problem is that the org.slf4j.LoggerFactory wants to load the SLF4JServiceProvider with the "LoggerFactory.class.getClassLoader()". And this is the org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader. With this no SLF4JServiceProvider will be found.
I found a workaround for this problem where i am using an other class loader:
Add logback to classpath:
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Test2
Bundle-SymbolicName: test2;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Eclipse-BundleShape: jar
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.swt,
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.workbench,
 org.eclipse.jface,
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.services,
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench,
 org.eclipse.e4.core.di,
 org.eclipse.e4.ui.di,
 org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 slf4j.api;bundle-version="2.0.12",
 ch.qos.logback.classic;bundle-version="1.5.0",
 ch.qos.logback.core;bundle-version="1.5.0"
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-17
Import-Package: jakarta.annotation;version="[2.1.0,3.0.0)",
 jakarta.inject;version="[2.0.0,3.0.0)",
 org.slf4j;version="[2.0.0,3.0.0]"
Automatic-Module-Name: test2
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Bundle-ClassPath: lib/ch.qos.logback.classic_1.5.6.jar,
 lib/ch.qos.logback.core_1.5.6.jar,
 lib/slf4j.api_2.0.13.jar,
 .

Code to init SLF4JServiceProvider:
    private static void initSLF4JServiceProvider() {
        
        ServiceLoader<SLF4JServiceProvider> serviceLoader = ServiceLoader.load(SLF4JServiceProvider.class);
        
        // init service provider manually
        Optional<SLF4JServiceProvider> serviceProviderOpt = serviceLoader.findFirst();       
        if (serviceProviderOpt.isEmpty()) {
            System.err.println("LogbackInitializer: No SLF4JServiceProvider found to init logging");
            return;
        }      
        SLF4JServiceProvider slf4jServiceProvider = serviceProviderOpt.get();
        slf4jServiceProvider.initialize();
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = slf4jServiceProvider.getLoggerFactory();

        Logger logger = loggerFactory.getLogger("test");
        logger.info("Test");
        
    }

Note: For logging we can no more use org.slf4j.LoggerFactory. We need to use ILoggerFactory from code above.

https://github.com/qos-ch/slf4j/issues/427

The code in initSLF4JServiceProvider creates a second logging system unrelated to the one used by LoggerFactory. Thus, it is not a general solution.
However, it is not clear if the first part of your answer is sufficient and whether initSLF4JServiceProvider was provided for illustration purposes only and is not actually needed.

Yes, you are right, this is just a workaround and not a solution to the problem. And yes you need the code of initSLF4JServiceProvider for the workaround.

Here is described a solution (not a workaround):
https://github.com/qos-ch/slf4j/issues/427
"SLF4J 2 assumes that a Service Loader Mediator like Apache SPI Fly is present in your OSGi environment. You need to add the bundle to your Equinox deployment."
https://docs.osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.loader.html
https://aries.apache.org/documentation/modules/spi-fly.html
Haven't had time to test it yet. Doesn't seem like an easy solution either. If anyone has gotten this to work, please write in the comment.
